# .htaccess problems: not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to install manually a applications developed by me on apache2 server based on debian 9...

I uploaded a .htaccess file on server by ssh, simply it should work. But it don't. 
The application is behind shop folder and I would transform http://localhost/shop/index.php/login to http://localhost/shop/login
When I try to go to url without index.php, apache showed me a 404 error!

I have done a lot of test under Windows (my localhost) with Xampp and everything worked well!

Code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase shop/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: do you have apache installed on your remote server?

Comment: yeah, with rewrite module enabled

Comment: so what happens when you go to /shop/login ?

Comment: apache showed me a 404 error page